# Finding index of a data frame comparing with another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Two data frames df and df1. Both have a column called description(which may not be unique). I wanted to get the index no of df where the description matches description of df1.

```
df      
    Name    des
0   xyz1    abc
1   xyz2    bcd
2   xyz3    nna
3   xyz4    mmm
4   xyz5    man



df1     
    des 
0   abc 
1   nna 
2   bcd 
3   man 


O/P required        
df1     
    des index_df
0   abc 0
1   nna 2
2   bcd 1
3   man 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with `.loc` accessor and using `reset_index` to elevate index to column:

```
res = df.loc[df['des'].isin(set(df1['des'])), 'des'].reset_index()

#    index  des
# 0      0  abc
# 1      1  bcd
# 2      2  nna
# 3      4  man
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` with swapped index and values created by column `des`:

```
s = pd.Series(df.index, index=df['des'])
df1['index_df'] = df1['des'].map(s)
print (df1)
   des  index_df
0  abc         0
1  nna         2
2  bcd         1
3  man         4
```